# How to vertically center multiline text with an image on its left?

Tags: css, layout

I want a 2-col grid of images and varying text in a matrix,
can't figure out how to do it with LI & css or similar. Please help out with concept or good resource.

(the grid will be used to populate a "fake" enhanched combobox.)

```
|  o o   |                                     |
|   ¨    | This text verically centered        |
|  ---   |  
------------------------------------------------
|  o o   |                                     |
|   ¨    | This text verically centered        |
|  ---   |                                     |
```

Code so far - no functioning valign:

```
<div class="list2" style="width:400px;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div style="float:left;border:1px solid #000;width:400px;">
        <img style="float:left;" src="imgcache/91427.jpg" height="60"/>
        <p style="margin-left:20px;float:left;">I want to be vert. centered.</p>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div style="float:left;border:1px solid #000;width:400px;">
       <img style="float:left;" src="52352.jpg" height="60"/>
       <p style="margin-left:20px;float:left;">I want to be vert. centered.</p>
     </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include at least your markup. Can the text be multiple lines or only a single line? Is the image size fixed? You question is quite vague right now.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will. Yes, the text may contain multiple rows so line-height not an option.

Comment: You should edit this into your question as well, just to avoid the thousand one-liner answers offering line-height and text-ellipsis. Also, you should specify which browsers should be supported.

Comment: Created a [nice jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8TFM/) that people can play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `display: table-cell` and `display: table-row`. I revised your markup a bit to only show the relevant and important parts, so you might have to tweak it a bit for your purposes. Please note that [IE 7 and lower do not support these properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

```
.list2 li {
    display: table-row;
}

.list2 img { 
    display: table-cell;
}
.list2 p { 
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 20px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8TFM/9/)

Vertical centering is not really possible in CSS2 without hacks like this (check out [Chris Coyier's post](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) also), but the [CSS3 Flexible Box Model](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/) could [help you](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/#toc-center) if you accept [the browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution using inline-block on the paragraph tags, and vertical-align:center on the image and paragraph tags.

[see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/uHzZR/](http://jsfiddle.net/uHzZR/)

```
<div class="list2" style="width:400px;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div style="float:left;border:1px solid #000;width:400px;">
        <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="imgcache/91427.jpg" height="100">
        <p style="margin-left:20px;width: 288px;vertical-align: middle;display: inline-block;">I want to be vert. safjsdfl asdf asf saf sdfsf sdfs fsffsd fdfss centered.</p>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div style="float:left;border:1px solid #000;width:400px;">
       <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="52352.jpg" height="60">
       <p style="margin-left:20px;vertical-align: middle;width: 288px;display: inline-block;">I want to be vert. centered.</p>
     </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>​
```